# Not able to sign App Store IPA when using SSH connection to run the command

Tags: jenkins, automation, putty, ipa

I have a bash script which ejects a react-native project, it then builds and signs an IPA before uploading that IPA to the App Store.
This script successful executes when run on a MacStadium machine that I’m developing on. This is the xcodebuild command:

`xcodebuild archive -workspace $NAME.xcworkspace  -allowProvisioningUpdates -scheme $NAME -configuration Release -archivePath ../builds/$NAME.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=$TEAM_ID CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic PROVISIONING_STYLE=Automatic PROVISIONING_PROFILE=""`

However when I try to execute the script through a SSH connection using Jenkins and even Putty to the MacStadium machine I receive the following error message:

`Code Signing Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'MY_APPLE_ID'. The login details for account 'MY_APPLE_ID' were rejected.`

As I said before the script executes and signs the IPA successfully when done within the machine. So my question is, is there something happening behind the scenes when I launch the script from for a remote location (The console I am using) that could be causing a conflict with signing the IPA?

Comment: The script inexplicably worked on a connection to a different machine, from looking into the machines a little more I think my issue was that I had not given codesign access to the keychain without needing a key, this wasn't an issue when running locally but fixed it when I redid my set-up